# Как изменить с помощью .style несколько параметров?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

```
document.getElementById("simple").style = "background-color: #000";
```

Как таким образом изменить несколько параметров `style`?
При создании таких же строк выполняется только последняя, игнорируются все предыдущие.

Comment: Рекомендую никогда так не делать. Задавать стили исключительно в CSS, а в JS только оперировать добавлением/удалением классов/идентификаторов этих самых стилей

Comment: Точно также, как в теге <style> - через точку с запятой. Например, "background-color: #000; color=#fff;"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно установить стили так:

```
document.getElementById("simple").style.cssText = `
  display: block; 
  position: absolute;
`;
```

или в одну строку

```
document.getElementById("simple").style.cssText = "display: block; position: absolute";
```

и

```
let styles = `
    font-size:15em;
    color:red;
    transform:rotate(20deg)`

document.getElementById("simple").style = styles;
```

тоже получится.

Но рекомендую никогда так не делать. Задавать стили исключительно в CSS, а в JS только оперировать добавлением/удалением классов/идентификаторов этих самых стилей